# Pipe groupByKey data in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pipe

I would like to transform following data set by external script piped from Apache Spark:

```
key,val1,val2
1,a,b
1,c,d
1,e,f
2,g,h
2,i,j
2,k,l
```

Data should be first grouped by the key and then all values passed to the external script using pipe()

I tried this code, but it calls the script just once and passes all data to it:

```
data.map(s => s.split(",")).map(a => (a(1),a)).groupByKey().pipe(Seq(SparkFiles.get("test.sh")))
```